# Conver text in numbers to digits

Tags: objective-c, iphone, apple-watch, siri

I have an application for the Apple Watch that uses Siri for getting input from the user. I need to get the response in numbers when the user speak, but the below method only returns numbers as strings, e.g. "five" instead of "5". Any help on how I can achieve this?

`presentTextInputControllerWithSuggestions`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[NSNumberFormatter](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/index.html) can convert from text to numbers.

**Example**

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle;

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"thirty-four"]);
NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"three point five"]);

formatter.locale = [[NSLocale alloc]initWithLocaleIdentifier:[NSLocale localeIdentifierFromComponents:@{NSLocaleLanguageCode: @"es"}]];

NSLog(@"%@", [formatter numberFromString:@"ocho"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this.

```
NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
formatter.numberStyle = NSNumberFormatterSpellOutStyle;
NSNumber *num = [formatter numberFromString:@"yourWord"];
int value = [num intValue];
```